# Security image is not available in boonex

Tags: boonex-dolphin

I have installed a new dolphin-boonex(7.1) cms.but at join.php page i can't see captcha image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Visit this link  http://www.google.com/recaptcha
2. Generate

   - reCAPTCHA public key
   - reCAPTCHA private key
3. Now go to your boonex admin **Admin -> Settings -> Advanced Settings**
4. Now open  Security tab in Advanced Settings page
5. Fill both key here
6. Clear your cache